# How can i send data from android to we using post method

Tags: android, post, http-post

i want to send a simple data from android device to asp.net page using post method..
but i didn't know how to request a web page from android!!!

asp page is good and can response a data without any errors..
but the problem in android application...

now i'm using this code but it didn't work

```
public void postData() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, Exception {       
    String key = "https://www.itrack.somee.com/post.aspx?id=10&long=123&lat=123&alt=123";
    //URI  uri=new URI(key);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(key);

    Toast.makeText(this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Toast.makeText(this,"mm"+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

any help.....!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `ArrayList` of `nameValuePairs` and attach them to an HttpPost with the `setEntity` method.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Var1",Var1_value));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Var2",Var2_value));
//...ect
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("URL_HERE");       
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was writing this as MrZander's answer popped in so... Building on @MrZander's answer, here is an example. If this works please mark his answer as accepted.

```
public void postData() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, Exception {       
    String key = "https://www.itrack.somee.com/post.aspx";
    //URI  uri=new URI(key);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(key);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "10"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", "123"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", "123"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alt", "123"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    Toast.makeText(this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Toast.makeText(this,"mm"+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

---

Or better yet, I believe you are looking for something like this maybe?:

```
public void postData(int id, double lat, double lng, double alt) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, Exception {       
    String key = "https://www.itrack.somee.com/post.aspx";
    //URI  uri=new URI(key);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(key);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "" + id));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", String.valueOf(lat));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", String.valueOf(lng));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alt", String.valueOf(alt)));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    Toast.makeText(this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Toast.makeText(this,"mm"+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

from my understanding of web services, post methods require that the URL parameters be sent in the body, not as part of the url

here your `key` variable features a url with post data as parameters when you need to set a body instead.

`get requests` use url parameters
`post requests` use headers and body